# FionaDeprecationWarning: Collection.__next__() is buggy and will be removed in Fiona 2.0. Switch to `next(iter(collection))`. record = next(c)

Tags: python, shapefile, python-3, fiona

I have some Python3 code used to import shapefiles using fiona. This is the main set of lines:

I created some code (Python3) with these lines:

```
c = fiona.open(dataDir + "/" + sourceFile, encoding=shapefileEncoding)
for i in range (0, len(c)):
                        # Get next record
                        record = next(c)
                        .......
c.closed
```

The code works perfectly but the output includes this warning:

```
FionaDeprecationWarning: Collection.__next__() is buggy and will be removed in Fiona 2.0. Switch to `next(iter(collection))`.  record = next(c)
```

I probably don't understand what iterable `iter` refers to. I replaced `next(c)` in my code with `next(iter(c))` and my code no longer works: I get the same record repeatedly instead of iterating through all records.

What should I replace the `next(c)` in my code with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just loop over the collection:

```
with fiona.open(dataDir + "/" + sourceFile, encoding=shapefileEncoding) as c:
    for record in c:
        do something with record
```

Using a context manager (the `with` statement) removes the need for closing the dataset explicitly.

If you need `i` (the record index) for anything, you can `enumerate`:

```
with fiona.open(dataDir + "/" + sourceFile, encoding=shapefileEncoding) as c:
    for i, record in enumerate(c):
        do something with record
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the VERY quick reply!